# Clear Input Box Every x Seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html, intervals

I'd like to know how to clear a text box every 'x' seconds using JavaScript (or whatever's best) in my HTML/PHP iPad WebApp.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This would be done with javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Vanilla javascript:** clears input value every 3 seconds

```js
setInterval(
  function() {
    document.getElementById("my-input").value = "";
  }, 3000);
```

```html
<input id="my-input" type="text" />
```

Comment: This is the method I decided to use! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

using jQuery you could do something like this;

where the 2000 is, this is the number of milliseconds (i.e. 2 seconds) to execute the function clear, which then finds the div you want to clear and empties it.  If it's a textbox value or something you want to clear just update the function to do what you need.

```
function clear() {
    $("#yourIdToEmpty").clear();
}
setTimeout(clear, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var interval = 1000; /*seconds * 1000. I'm using 1000 */
  setInterval(function(){
    $("#input").val('');
  }, interval);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='input'/>
```